# How can I add UrlRewriteFilter in Spring Boot

Tags: java, filter, spring-boot

```
    <filter>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

I want to convert above given filter in Spring boot code.

Comment: In what way is it not working?

Comment: It is not rewriting urls.

Comment: Post some configuration and your spring boot startup class. Which URLs are you calling and what did you expect.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This Answer works for me.

```
@Bean
public UrlRewriteFilter getUrlRewriteFilter() {
    log.debug("Calling Bean URL Rewrite Filter");
    UrlRewriteFilter urlRewriteFilter = new UrlRewriteFilter();
    return urlRewriteFilter;
}
```

We are supposed to add urlrewrite.xml file in WEB-INF folder.