# How to provide a specific link to angularJs routed page

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot, angular-ui-router

I have an angularJs application, which uses $routeProvider to handle internal routing. The back end uses Rest controllers within a Spring Boot application. The application is based on this: https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/

What I want to do is send an email with an embedded link similar to "http://localhost:8080/link/key1234". The user should be able to click this, and go to specific content as indicated by the key1234 variable.

I have seen a similar item ([Refreshing page gives "Page not found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14168836/refreshing-page-gives-page-not-found)) which suggests using .htaccess to handle this, but I do not currently have a .htaccess file.

I also have html5mode on [$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);]

Another suggestion ([Spring Boot with AngularJS html5Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24837715/spring-boot-with-angularjs-html5mode)) is to intercept the request and redirect to the home page. Whilst this prevents the application from failing, I need the user to go to a specific page, not the Home page.

I have managed to get quite confused about the interactions of my different components. Can you point me in the right direction to enable a specific link to be provided ?

### UPDATE

I think that the .htaccess file is a red herring.

The spring.io tutorial includes the following code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{[path:[^\\.]*}")
public String redirect() {
  return "forward:/";
}
```

And this segment performs a redirect for **some** of the pages.

However, my tests (until recently) had been using "http://localhost:8080/public/about" which is not getting picked up by the RequestMapping snippet above.

If I use a single level url (e.g. "http://localhost:8080/test") then my existing code works fine.

It looks like there is a flaw in this regex.

Comment: Is your client running in the same Spring Boot application, or you are using a different server, like "grunt serve"?

Comment: Why I asked it because, whatever server your client is running on, whether on the same application or "grunt serve," you would need to find the equivalent of .htaccess.

Comment: Thank you Sanjay. At the moment, my client is running through Spring Boot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a request like `http://localhost:8080/link/key1234` hits your server, you would need to forward the request to home page. Then, the client should get the response of the home page, while the URL will still be `http://localhost:8080/link/key1234`. *html5mode* will then come to play, changing the *view* at the client side.

I think the best way to do it might be to use [urlrewrite filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30476586/how-can-i-add-urlrewritefilter-in-spring-boot), which should forward all requests except those starting with, say `/api/**`, to the home page.

Comment: Thank you, this has helped a lot. (Unfortunately  cannot up vote the answer)